# How do I sort if the information is in a different Laravel table?

Tags: php, laravel

Initially, I had an enum list and this sorting was written for it (everything works well)

```
->orderByRaw("CASE state
              WHEN 'Open' THEN 1
              WHEN 'Active' THEN 2
              WHEN 'Closed' THEN 3
              ELSE 4
              END")
```

This was an enum list of project states
How do I make the code above work? So that it works with another table (states), also sorting.

I have projects table that contains `state_id` column and I have `states` table that contains `id` and `state_name`

I know I can set the correct order in the states table
and then `sort - - - > order By ('state_id')`. However, this is wrong, I think.

Comment: Did you move your `state enum` to it's dedicated table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using [ORDER BY FIELD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field)

```
 $value = DB::table('projects')->join('states', 'projects.state_id', 'states.id')
  ->where('states.state_name', '!=', 'Process')
  ->orderByRaw("FIELD(state_name,'Open','Active','Closed')")
   ->paginate(7);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I can't understand, but how will it understand that these values need to be taken from the 'states' table ?

Comment: please share the query you want to sort by state_name

Comment: https://codepen.io/rik123/pen/ZEOwvYa. In the HTML field, I added a Laravel query that worked with enum-list. Expand it a bit

Comment: I have edited my answer to match the result you want

Answer (score 2):

Easy solution is to put a new field named `priority` to your `states` table which is an `unsigned tiny integer` then you can easily sort by priority field

```php
$projects = Project::join('states', 'states.id', '=', 'projects.state_id')
    ->orderBy('states.priority', 'asc')->select('projects.*')->get();

dd($projects->toArray());
```

and if you insist to sort by `states.state_name` you can do this

```php
$projects = Project::join('states', 'states.id', '=', 'projects.state_id')
    ->orderByRaw("CASE states.state_name
              WHEN 'Open' THEN 1
              WHEN 'Active' THEN 2
              WHEN 'Closed' THEN 3
              ELSE 4
              END")->select('projects.*')->get();
dd($projects->toArray());
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer and explanation (sorry, I can't give 2 best answers, I have too low reputation, sorry)

Comment: nice explanation